# Data Frame: mean over certain variables, ignore but keep others

Tags: r, dataframe, sum, mean, reorganize

I am analysing my data with R for the first time which is a bit challenging. I have a data frame with my data that looks like this:

```
head(data)
      subject group age trial cond acc  rt
    1   S1     2     1     1   1    1   5045
    2   S1     2     1     2   2    1   8034
    3   S1     2     1     3   1    1   6236
    4   S1     2     1     4   2    1   8087
    5   S1     2     1     5   3    0   8756
    6   S1     2     1     6   1    1   6619
```

I would like to compute a mean and standard deviation for each subject in each condition for rt and a sum for each subject in each condition for acc. All the other variables are should remain the same (group and age are subject-specific, and trial can be disregarded).

I have tried using aggregate but that seemed kind of complicated because I had to do it in several steps and re-add information...

I'd be thankful for any help =)

Edit: I realise that I wasn't being clear. I want trial to be disregarded and end up with one row per subject per condition:

```
head(data_new)
      subject group age cond rt_mean  rt_sd    acc_sum
    1   S1     2     1  1    7581     100      5
    2   S2     2     1  2    8034     150      4
```

Sorry about the confusion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package `dplyr` is made for this:

```
library(dplyr)
d %>% 
  group_by(subject, cond) %>% # we group by the two values
  summarise(
    mean_rt = mean(rt, na.rm=T),
    sd_rt = sd(rt, na.rm=T),
    sum_acc = sum(acc, na.rm=T) # here we apply each function to summarise values
  )


# A tibble: 3 x 5
# Groups:   subject [?]
  subject  cond mean_rt sd_rt sum_acc
  <fct>   <int>   <dbl> <dbl>   <int>
1 S1          1   5967. 821.        3
2 S1          2   8060.  37.5       2
3 S1          3   8756   NA         0
# NA for the last sd_rt is because you can't have 
# sd for a single obs.
```

Basically you need to `group_by` the columns (one or more) that you need to use as grouping, then inside `summarise`, you apply each function you need (`mean`, `sd`, `sum`, ecc) to each variable (`rt`, `acc`, ecc).

Change `summarise` with `mutate` if you want to keep all variables:

```
d %>% 
  select(-trial) %>% # use select with -var_name to eliminate columns 
  group_by(subject, cond) %>% 
  mutate(
    mean_rt = mean(rt, na.rm=T),
    sd_rt = sd(rt, na.rm=T),
    sum_acc = sum(acc, na.rm=T)
  ) %>% 
  ungroup()
# A tibble: 6 x 9
subject group   age  cond   acc    rt mean_rt sd_rt sum_acc
<fct>   <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>   <dbl> <dbl>   <int>
1 S1          2     1     1     1  5045   5967. 821.        3
2 S1          2     1     2     1  8034   8060.  37.5       2
3 S1          2     1     1     1  6236   5967. 821.        3
4 S1          2     1     2     1  8087   8060.  37.5       2
5 S1          2     1     3     0  8756   8756   NA         0
6 S1          2     1     1     1  6619   5967. 821.        3
```

**Update** based on op request, maybe this is what you need:

```
d %>% 
  group_by(subject, cond, group, age) %>% 
  summarise(
    mean_rt = mean(rt, na.rm=T),
    sd_rt = sd(rt, na.rm=T),
    sum_acc = sum(acc, na.rm=T)
  ) 
# A tibble: 3 x 7
# Groups:   subject, cond, group [?]
subject  cond group   age mean_rt sd_rt sum_acc
<fct>   <int> <int> <int>   <dbl> <dbl>   <int>
1 S1          1     2     1   5967. 821.        3
2 S1          2     2     1   8060.  37.5       2
3 S1          3     2     1   8756   NA         0
```

Data used:

```
tt <- "subject group age trial cond acc  rt
S1     2     1     1   1    1   5045
S1     2     1     2   2    1   8034
S1     2     1     3   1    1   6236
S1     2     1     4   2    1   8087
S1     2     1     5   3    0   8756
S1     2     1     6   1    1   6619"

d <- read.table(text=tt, header=T)
```

Comment: Thanks! Generally, it looks good, however, if I use summarise, I lose all the variables that I wanted to keep the same (e.g. group) but if I use mutate, the doesn't eliminate "duplicate" rows... Is there a way to disregard "trial" and get one row per subject in each condition?

Comment: Hi see my update, use `select(-trial)` in order to remove that column.

Comment: if you need to add more grouping conditions try something like `group_by(subject, cond, group)`, in `group_by` you can add more variables.

Comment: basically if you need more grouping variables just add the min `group_by()`

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using the `data.table` package:

```
library(data.table)
data <- data.table(data)
data[, ':=' (rt_mean = mean(rt), rt_sd = sd(rt), acc_sum = sum(acc)), by = .(subject, cond)]
data

   subject group age trial cond acc   rt  rt_mean     rt_sd acc_sum
1:      S1     2   1     1    1   1 5045 5966.667 820.83758       3
2:      S1     2   1     2    2   1 8034 8060.500  37.47666       2
3:      S1     2   1     3    1   1 6236 5966.667 820.83758       3
4:      S1     2   1     4    2   1 8087 8060.500  37.47666       2
5:      S1     2   1     5    3   0 8756 8756.000        NA       0
6:      S1     2   1     6    1   1 6619 5966.667 820.83758       3
```

**Edit:**

If you want to get rid of some of the variables and duplicated rows, you need only a small modification - remove the `:=` assignment operator (instead of adding new colums, it will now create a new `data.table`), add the variables you want to keep and use the `unique` function:

```
unique(dt[, .(group, age, rt_mean = mean(rt), rt_sd = sd(rt), acc_sum = sum(acc)), by = .(subject, cond)])
   subject cond group age  rt_mean     rt_sd acc_sum
1:      S1    1     2   1 5966.667 820.83758       3
2:      S1    2     2   1 8060.500  37.47666       2
3:      S1    3     2   1 8756.000        NA       0
```

If you additionally want to get rid of rows with missing values, use the `na.omit` function.

Comment: First of all thank you for your help. This looks really close but I'm sorry, I described my issue a bit unclear/wrong: I would like to get rid of trials and end up with one row per subject per condition instead of having the same rt_mean for each trial of a specific condition and subject.

Comment: @Max Ok, it would require a simple modification, I edited the answer to adress it :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compute for example the mean of rt for subject S1 under condition 1, you can use `mean(data[data$subject == "S1" & data$cond == 1, 7])`.

I hope this gives you an idea how you can filter your values.